# Vite project builds locally but not in CI - Buffer issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, buffer, vite

Locally, Vite builds just fine. However, in CI (which just runs the same script, `npm run build`), it fails.

I get this error in CI:

```
Error:  "Buffer" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "src/index.html?html-proxy&index=0.js".
file: /home/runner/work/explorer/explorer/src/index.html?html-proxy&index=0.js:2:13
1: 
2:     import { Buffer } from "buffer";
                ^
3:     window.Buffer = Buffer;
Error:  error during build:
RollupError: "Buffer" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "src/index.html?html-proxy&index=0.js".
```

I added the line that is causing the error because of an issue when running `vite serve` locally (it errors) - StackOverflow suggested this solution. It builds fine even in CI without that line.

Here's my Vite config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr'
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html'
import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment'
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'

export default defineConfig({
  root: './src',
  envDir: '..',
  build: {
    // relative to the root
    outDir: '../build',
  },
  // relative to the root
  publicDir: '../public',
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:5001',
    },
  },
  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      events: 'events',
      stream: 'stream-browserify',
      zlib: 'browserify-zlib',
      'util/': 'util',
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        // Node.js global to browser globalThis
        global: 'globalThis',
      },
      // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          buffer: true,
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    svgrPlugin({
      exportAsDefault: true,
    }),
    react({
      // Use React plugin in all *.jsx and *.tsx files
      include: '**/*.{jsx,tsx}',
    }),
    createHtmlPlugin({
      inject: {
        data: {
          VITE_GA_ID: process.env.VITE_GA_ID,
          VITE_ZENDESK_KEY: process.env.VITE_ZENDESK_KEY,
        },
      },
    }),
    EnvironmentPlugin('all'),
    NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
      buffer: true,
      process: true,
    }),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    setupFiles: 'src/setupTests.js',
  },
})
```

My build command is `DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM=true vite build --emptyOutDir`

My serve command is `DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM=true vite serve`

Comment: My first thought is you didn't add a Yarn/Npm install command prior to the build and the required package is missing. If that doesn't work, a snippet of your CI script would help in troubleshooting.